# Protecting Route based on whether user has access to

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm building what (I think) should be a simple access protection on React Router to protect a given `spec` at route `/spec/:id` based on whether or not the user has access to that spec. A user's access to the spec is denoted by whether their `id: string` appears in the spec's `shared: string[]` field

The expected behavior, when the user does not have access, is they are re-directed to the home page at `/`. In the case below, where the user does not have access, instead I'm left at `/spec/:id` with no errors in the console. Can anyone point out why this is the case? Thanks so much

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getSpecById } from "../Models/Spec";
import { AuthContext } from "../Util/Auth";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isOwner, setIsOwner] = useState<boolean>(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOwnership() {
      const specData = await getSpecById(id);
      if (specData && currentUser) {
        console.log(specData.shared.includes(currentUser.uid)); //logs false
        setIsOwner(specData.shared.includes(currentUser.uid));
      }
    }
    fetchOwnership();
  });

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps: any) => {
        isOwner ? (
          <Component {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/"} />
        )
      }}
    />
    )
  };

export default ProtectedRoute
```

And this is me calling the `<ProtectedRoute>`

`<ProtectedRoute exact path="/spec/:id" render={() => (<Spec isEdit={true}/> )}/>`

---

**EDIT**
Based on feedback from Jason, I reworked the state variable containing `isOwner` to use `useRef()`. But the `Redirect` is still not being called. I'm not being sent back to `"/"` even though `isOwner` is equal to `false`

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const isOwner = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOwnership() {
      const specData = await getSpecById(id);
      if (specData && currentUser) {
        isOwner.current = specData.shared.includes(currentUser.uid);
      }
    }
    fetchOwnership();
  });

  console.log(isOwner.current);

  if (isOwner.current === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps: any) => {
        isOwner.current ? (
          <Component {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/"} />
        )
      }}
    />
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Redirect isn't being called at all. In the first render, `isOwner` is false (default value given to useState) so you should be getting immediately redirected (if everything were to work properly);

I assume the `Route` tag is not rendering its children. Is it given a `path` prop from `{...rest}`?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. I've updated the Q to include me calling it. And good callout that I would be redirected even if it works correctly, is there any way to mitigate that and check against the DB before I render the Route?

Comment: Sure, don't initialize isOwner, then `if (isOwner === undefined) return null;`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah makes sense. But you're right the redirect isn't even being called, so I'm still not sent back to `"/"`

Answer (score -2):

You can't call the async function inside useEffect hook directly, You have to use IIFE methodology. here is an example I used.

```
useEffect(() => {
 (async () => {
  const users = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?page=1&results=10&nat=us");
  setUsers(users.data.results);
 })();
}, []);
```

in your case

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOwnership() {
      const specData = await getSpecById(id);
      if (specData && currentUser) {
        console.log(specData.shared.includes(currentUser.uid)); //logs false
        setIsOwner(specData.shared.includes(currentUser.uid));
      }
    }()
    
  });
```

Comment: There is no difference between immediately invoking a named function and calling it by name after declaring it